# kafka controller broker is unable to create a topic

Tags: docker, apache-kafka

I am using a Dockerized static Kafka cluster (0.11) having 3 brokers. The problem with this cluster is that the controller node is not allowing me to create a topic if all the brokers are running on the same port.

However, if all brokers are running on a different port, it is working fine.

My question is why it is not working on the same port, though I am running each broker on a different node?

Here is my broker configuration template:

```
auto.leader.rebalance.enable=true
broker.id.generation.enable=false
broker.id={{KAFKA_BROKER_ID}}
auto.create.topics.enable=true
default.replication.factor={{DEFAULT_REPLICATION_FACTOR}}
min.insync.replicas={{MIN_INSYNC_REPLICAS}}
offsets.topic.replication.factor={{DEFAULT_REPLICATION_FACTOR}}
offsets.commit.required.acks={{MIN_INSYNC_REPLICAS}}
advertised.host.name={{KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME}}
delete.topic.enable={{KAFKA_DELETE_TOPIC_ENABLE}}
message.max.bytes={{KAFKA_MESSAGE_MAX_BYTES}}
replica.fetch.max.bytes={{KAFKA_MESSAGE_MAX_BYTES}}
port={{KAFKA_PORT}}
advertised.port={{KAFKA_ADVERTISED_PORT}}
log.dir=/data/{{KAFKA_BROKER_ID}}
log.dirs=/data/{{KAFKA_BROKER_ID}}
num.partitions={{KAFKA_NUM_PARTITIONS}}
log.retention.hours={{LOG_RETENTION_HOURS}}
zookeeper.connect={{ZOOKEEPER_CONNECTION_STRING}}{{ZOOKEEPER_CHROOT}}
zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms={{ZOOKEEPER_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT_MS}}
zookeeper.session.timeout.ms={{ZOOKEEPER_SESSION_TIMEOUT_MS}}
zookeeper.sync.time.ms=10000
controlled.shutdown.enable=true
group.max.session.timeout.ms={{GROUP_MAX_SESSION_TIMEOUT_MS}}
unclean.leader.election.enable=false
controller.socket.timeout.ms=120000
num.recovery.threads.per.data.dir=5
num.replica.fetchers=3
```

Comment: so you're saying that each dockerized Kafka containter is on a different host machine?

Comment: Yes , each one is on different host machine.

Comment: hard to diagnose with the information you've given. can you post the broker configs for the non-working brokers.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you're using deprecated variables in your configuration file. Remove `advertised.host.name`, `advertised.port`, and `port`. All you need to do is set `listeners=PLAINTEXT://:9092`. If port 9092 is exposed on each of your containers and each of those containers is on a different node, has a different `broker.id`, and is connected to the same ZooKeeper cluster, your brokers should be able to communicate with each other without any issues.